# PostgreSQL: Table partitioning by the first byte of column of BYTEA type

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, bitcoin

Could PostgreSQL be able to split the table into 256 partitions by the first byte of one BYTEA column?
I'm trying to insert Bitcoin transactions into PostgreSQL. There are currently ~622 468 868 in total. At the beginning, without partitions, everything looked promising, but after 10M records, the performance of the inserts has decreased. One of the columns (TX) contains 32 bytes which is the transaction identifier. I thought that based on the first byte of this column, I could divide this table into 256 partitions - but I don't know if PostreSQL allows it?

Current definition of my table:

```
create table t_tx (
    id          serial      primary key
,   txid        bytea       not null
,   block_id    integer     not null
,   n           smallint    not null
);
```

Comment: It is possible, but it wouldn't be helpful. If at all, hash partitioning on the complete `txid` might help. I assume `txid` must already be unique (and will never change), so I don't see any benefit on adding _another_ unique column (`id`)

Comment: For what it is worth, `txid` will not be unique on bitcoin - there are a handful of transactions with duplicate txids.